# How to compare null value from the JsonObject in java

Tags: java, json, hibernate, extjs4

stackoverflow member i need some help from you.

I am having a JsonObject given below

```
{
"Id": null,
"Name": "New Task",
"StartDate": "2010-03-05T00:00:00",
"EndDate": "2010-03-06T00:00:00",
"Duration": 1,
"DurationUnit": "d",
"PercentDone": 60,
"ManuallyScheduled": false,
"Priority": 1,
"parentId": null,
"index": 2,
"depth": 1,
"checked": null }
```

i am getting parentId as null. I want to replace the parentId value from null to 0.

I am trying to do it with below mentioned code

```
if(jsonObject.get("parentId") == null || jsonObject.get("parentId") == "")
    {
        System.out.println("inside null");
        jsonObject.put("parentId", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("inside else part");
        //jsonObject.put("parentId", jsonObject.getInt("parentId"));
        jsonObject.put("parentId", 0);
    }
```

but it seems not to be working. What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What happens with the json object after the code is executed? What is the output prom the System.out.printlns? Is JsonObject requirement or just the Json parser you chose?

Comment: i am not getting any output. but before if condition if i put the **System.out.println("JSON OBJECT VALUE FOR PARENTID ::"+jsonObject.get("parentId"));** i am getting the printout value as **null** so i want to check it using if condition but it always goes to else part only. Don't know what's the problem in this

Comment: "i am not getting any output" what do you mean? Either you get the println from the 'then' case or from the 'else' one.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use the following method of JsonObject to check if a value against any key is null

```
public boolean isNull(java.lang.String key)
```

This method is used to check Null against any key or if there is no value for the key.

check this in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#isNull-java.lang.String-)

Your Modified code should be like this

```
if(jsonObject.isNull("parentId"))
    {
        System.out.println("inside null");
        jsonObject.put("parentId", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("inside else part");
        //jsonObject.put("parentId", jsonObject.getInt("parentId"));
        jsonObject.put("parentId", 0);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but my jsonlib-2.2.3.jar doesn't have **isNull** method declaration in it. so how to compare nll object form json data. ??

Comment: In jsonlib-2.2.3.jar, check net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils class has isNull method

Comment: yes.. rao i did it using JSONUtils class **boolean jsonUtils = JSONUtils.isNull(jsonObject.get("parentId"));** thanx for your support

Comment: @RajeshPantula this is not working in `json.simple.*` what to be use in `json.simple`

Answer (score 6):

```
if(jsonObject.isNull("parentId")){
    jsonObject.put("parentId", 0);
}
```

Comment: this is not working in `json.simple.*` what to be use in `json.simple`

Answer (score 5):

For com.google.gson.JsonObject, I followed this :

```
boolean isIdNull = jsonObject.get("Id").isJsonNull();
```

In my json, I have :

```
"Id":null
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using org.json.JSONObject in 2020,
if you have {"key":null}

Check the value of the key by JSONObject.NULL

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{"key":null}");
Object value = json.get("key");
if (value == JSONObject.NULL){
  ...
}
```

Comment: JSONObject.NULL was the answer I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following codes.

```
if(jsonObject.isNull("parentId") || jsonObject.get("parentId").equals(""))
```

Comment: this is not working in `json.simple.*` what to be use in `json.simple`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the next code

```
int parentId = jsonObject.optInt("parentId", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

These two methods works

`if( jsonObject.get("parentId").equals(null) )`

`if( jsonObject.isNull("parentId") )`

Because the JSONObject has its own Null class, so java primitive `null` is not same as `Null()` in JSONObject.

[image]