# Why null is not equal to null?

Tags: java, json, equals

I dont understand what is happening in my application. I'm sending PUT request with updates from Angular project to java api. I have a method that validates query parameters from the put request, the method looks like this:

```
private JsonObject validateRequestBody(JsonElement requestBody) {
    if (!(requestBody instanceof JsonObject)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request body cannot be case to JSON object");
    }
    JsonObject bodyObj = requestBody.getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(bodyObj.get("entityIri").equals(null));
    if (bodyObj.get("entityIri") == null) {
        System.out.println("null");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request body must contain entity IRI");
    }
    return bodyObj;
}
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to check if the `enityIri` paramter is equal to null. To test it, Im sending `null` as `entityIri` from Angular project. I tried to compare them with `equal` method and with `==`, but in both cases the output is always false. Could someone explain me why they are not equal? Is it because I'm passing it to `JsonObject`? 
I attach a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Agf.png) from debugging (I cut out irrelevant parts).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare null value from the JsonObject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802236/how-to-compare-null-value-from-the-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: `bodyObj.get()` will return instance of `JsonObject` and it is not `null`, you can call `getAsString()` or whatever to perform such verification

Comment: I tried comparing `bodyObj.get("entityIri")` to `"null"`, but it was also false. Besides in the screenshot, its visible that during debugging, the value of  `bodyObj.get("entityIri")` is null, not a string because it doesnt have quotation marks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [isJsonNull](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#isJsonNull()) method:

> provides check for verifying if this element represents a null value
>   or not.

```
if (bodyObj.get("entityIri").isJsonNull()) {
    ...
}
```

Of course, you need to check whether `bodyObj.get("entityIri")` is not `null` before. I did not add it statement to make statement clear.

Comment: Which of course will throw `NullPointerException` if `entityIri` is missing.

Comment: @Andreas, I just wanted to make it clear how to use it. But, of course, you are right. I added extra comment that checking `null` is good idea.